# Animation OpenModelica

Tags: animation, simulation, modelica, openmodelica

I would like to create a animation of my example below:

```
   model toto
  Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume volume(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Examples.TwoPhaseWater, V = 1e-3, nPorts = 1, p_start = 400e5, use_HeatTransfer = true, use_T_start = true, use_portsData = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-50, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 90)));
  inner Modelica.Fluid.System system(T_start(displayUnit = "K") = 300, p_start(displayUnit = "Pa") = 100000) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-86, 84}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Examples.TwoPhaseWater, diameter = 6.2e-3, length = 484e-3, nParallel = 1) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-16, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Components.MassWithStopAndFriction NoirStop(F_Coulomb = 0, F_Stribeck = 0, F_prop = 0, m = 1, s(fixed = true, start = 0), smax = 0.2, smin = 0) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {46, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Machines.SweptVolume NoirCylinder(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Examples.TwoPhaseWater, clearance = 7982e-9, nPorts = 1, pistonCrossArea = 301e-6, use_T_start = true, use_portsData = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {16, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Components.Mass mass(m = 482, s(fixed = true, start = 0)) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {76, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
  connect(volume.ports[1], pipe.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-40, 0}, {-26, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(NoirCylinder.flange, NoirStop.flange_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{26, 0}, {36, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 0}));
  connect(NoirStop.flange_b, mass.flange_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{56, 0}, {66, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 0}));
  connect(pipe.port_b, NoirCylinder.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-6, 0}, {6, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "4.0.0")));
end toto;
```

To be able to do the same thing as for the OpenModelica example Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Examples.Elementary.DoublePendulum.
However, I don't know how to do it, do you have any ideas please?

Comment: The model is not complete, because CurvedBendModel is not available.

Comment: Yes, excuse me, I had modified my CurvedBend component. So I've removed it from my model for now...

Answer (score 0):

For a 3D animation you can use the provided visualizer components of [Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Visualizers](https://doc.modelica.org/Modelica%204.0.0/Resources/helpOM/Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Visualizers.html).

Comment: To be honest with you, I had seen these components, but unfortunately I don't know how to connect them to complete my animation.